# Error while loading shared libraries: libopenal.so.1 (Game 'pacapong' in Ubuntu 14.10)

Tags: games

I downloaded the game [pacapong](http://kingpenguin.itch.io/pacapong) for Linux and tried to run the executable, which results in the error:

```
$ ./runner 

./runner: error while loading shared libraries: libopenal.so.1: 
cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Obviously, there is the necessity of loading `libopenal.so.1`:

```
$ objdump -p ./runner |grep libopenal.so.1

NEEDED libopenal.so.1
```

There is `libopenal.so.1` lying in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu` and I can do:

```
$ ldd libopenal.so.1
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fffcdbbb000)
```

...

I won't run this executable (./runner) as root (just in case this problem could be related to insufficient rights, what I'm not assuming).

So, what could I try else?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The error is because this is a 32-bit game that you are trying to run in 64-bit Linux. I worked through the errors by googling error messages to figure out what packages I was missing. I ended up installing the following packages to get the game to run:

```
sudo apt-get install libxxf86vm1:i386 libglu1-mesa:i386 libopenal1:i386 libssl1.0.0:i386
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate on what installing these packages does and how it solves the issues?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it solves the problem.

There you think to know everything about the system, well and actually you know about it, but you don't think of it... ;)

Comment: This. GOG bundles games linked with 32-bit Linux (ugggh, why) so if you have a 64-bit machine you have to have BOTH the OpenGL/etc libraries for 64-bit and 32-bit versions.  It's extra confusing because it tells you you're missing libraries you know you have.

Answer (score 1):

For the future, running ldd on ./runner will tell you the libraries it requires, if they're missing, AND if they're i386 or 64-bit.

$ ldd on ./runner

> /undertale/game$ ldd ./runner
>
> linux-gate.so.1 (0xf7798000)
>
> libgtk3-nocsd.so.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgtk3-nocsd.so.0 (0xf7759000)
>
> libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0xf75d3000)
>
> ...
>
> libXrandr.so.2 => not found
>
> libbsd.so.0 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libbsd.so.0 (0xf6b41000)
>
> libXau.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXau.so.6 (0xf6b3d000)
>
> libXdmcp.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXdmcp.so.6 (0xf6b36000)

Note I'm still missing xrandr for i386. So this isn't going to work yet.

$ ./runner

> ./runner: error while loading shared libraries: >libXrandr.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Answer (score 1):

Use `apt-file` tool to find out which package provides the required library. If you do not have the search tool first install it

```
sudo apt-get install apt-file
```

If this is the first time you are going to use `apt-file` tool you must update cache first

```
apt-file update # it may require root privileges. If so just use sudo
```

Now search the library:

```
apt-file search libXrandr.so.2
libxrandr2: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXrandr.so.2
libxrandr2: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXrandr.so.2.2.0
```

Now install the 32 bit package you need

```
sudo apt-get install libxrandr2:i386
```