# Civilization 6 on Ubuntu 18.04 missing libopenal.so.1

Tags: 18.04, games, steam

I'm trying to run Civilization 6 from steam. I get a message saying "an unrecoverable error has occured, and civilization 6 cannot continue".

I'm looking through some solutions here, where I found that I could run the Civ6 executable directly from the directory `~/.steam/steam/steamapps/common/Sid Meier's Civilization VI`.

When I run it from that directory in terminal I get back:

```
./Civ6: error while loading shared libraries: libopenal.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I found some [similar questions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/608418/error-while-loading-shared-libraries-libopenal-so-1-game-pacapong-in-ubuntu) which recommend installing various packages but none of them have worked.

Comment: To use the answer below you should enable [universe repository](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/libopenal1) - see possible duplicate of [How do I enable the "Universe" repository from the command line?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/78613/how-do-i-enable-the-universe-repository-from-the-command-line)

Comment: @N0rbert it's already enabled...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install libdevel

```
sudo apt install libdevel libopenal1
```

this installs Openal audio API needed for Civilization 6 :)

Comment: I get `E: Unable to locate package libdevel` are you using 16.04?

Comment: sorry I forgot I upgraded to 18.04

Comment: libopenal1 should actually fix the error, is it still showing ?

Comment: I have the same error on ubuntu 18.04

Comment: did this fix for you ?

Comment: you can simply "sudo apt install libopenal1" or download the package manually but repository is always recommended.