# error while loading shared libraries: libopenal.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: 64-bit, games, 32-bit

I am trying to play a 32 bit game on a Ubuntu 20.04 64 bit system, I added the installs in the best answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/608418/error-while-loading-shared-libraries-libopenal-so-1-game-pacapong-in-ubuntu), but I still get the above error. If I try

```
apt-file search libopenal.so.1
```

I get

```
libopenal1: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopenal.so.1
libopenal1: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopenal.so.1.19.1
```

And if I try

```
sudo apt-get install libopenal1:i386
```

I get

```
libopenal1:i386 is already the newest version (1:1.19.1-1)
```

Comment: Yep, when it is already installed it will not let you install it again.  The output of `dpkg -l | grep libopenal1` should show you and when the line starts with `ii` means that it is installed into the system.  You may need to only worry about the other applications on that installation line.

Comment: When I run that I get the output

ii  libopenal1:i386                            1:1.19.1-1                            i386         Software implementation of the OpenAL audio API (shared library)

Comment: So it can't find it because I need to uninstall 1.19.1 and reinstall libopenal1 with a lower version?

Comment: You should start with your OS & release

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04 is that

Comment: What game are you trying to run?

Comment: Icewind Dale enhanced edition from gog

Comment: Honestly, that would be up to GOG to update their games to work with Ubuntu 20.04.  You might have to look around and see what maybe others have done to solve the issues they were having with it.  https://www.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/ll9mmz/icewind_dale_not_launching/  You might also have to install these packages:  https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/gemrb-icewind-dale

Comment: How are those installed?

Comment: `sudo apt install <package name>` from a terminal window

Comment: Installing gemrb-icewind-dale worked, I had not seen this page before, thx